# Importance of strings of length less than or equal to $2^{V+1}$ generated by a grammar in CNF , where V is number of non terminal symbols?

Tags: context-free

I have this question: prove that the problem of testing whether a Context free grammar generates some string in $1^*$ is decidable.

I know one way to prove it. But I saw a different way of its proof which says that-

> Convert the context free grammar to chomsky normal form. Then compute all derivations of length less than or equal to $2^{n+1}$ , where n is the number of non terminal symbols in the CNF grammar. if no $1^*$ is derivable in this many steps then none will ever be.

I don't know how to correctly approach proving this statement. By looking at $2^{n+1}$ I was getting the idea that parse tree will have repetition of some non terminal(s) which implies there is a loop in grammar. I don't know if it is related to the proof.

Kindly explain how should I approach this.

Comment: Every subset of a word in $1^*$ is also a word in $1^*$, so if you encounter a loop in the parsing tree, you can take a look at the "inside" of the loop, and throw the "outside" part of it, and you will get something in $1^*$ as well.

Comment: @nirshahar , i am getting your point. what I can derive from "larger part" , I can also derive it using a "smaller part" by replacing the first occurrence of repeated variable with its second occurrence. But how does it Prove that all the strings generated within $2^{n+1}$ length are the only ones of significance?

Comment: My guess would be that any higher length would result in such a "loop". Then, each time you see a loop remove the un-necessary part of it, and each time it will just decrease the length. Continue to do this until the length is smaller than $2^{n+1}$

Comment: Since I am focusing on proper proof and build correct way of thinking, I will just say what you told. Please tell me whether my thinking is correct:- So you are saying that we keep trimming the tree until length becomes smaller than $2^{n+1}$ . Now we have a string of the form 1* having length less than $2^{n+1}$.  So this means if the language truly contains some string of form 1* then there must be some string of form 1* having length less than $2^{n+1}$. That is why we can only check strings of length less than or equal to $2^{n+1}$ and decide the answer is yes or no.

Comment: Yes, but this is only correct if we understood correctly that if the length is higher than $2^{n+1}$ then there is such a "loop". anyways, this can be considered only intuition. a formal proof would require rigorous proofs of why such a thing happens.

Comment: @nirshahar thank you! Also, will you tell me one more thing that what is the length of the smallest derivation which ensures a "loop"? Is it $2^{n-1} +1$ ,where n is the number of non terminals ?

Comment: P.S. the grammar is in chomsky normal form